# Evaluating an integral with $x^2 + x + 1$ in the denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

Problem:

Perform the following  integration:
$$ \int \dfrac{ dx } {x^2 + x + 1} $$

Answer:
$$ \int \dfrac{ dx } {x^2 + x + 1} $$
Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ dx } {\left( x + \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^2 + \dfrac{3}{4} }
\end{align*}
Now we use the substitution $u = x + \dfrac{1}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ du } {u^2 + \dfrac{3}{4} } \\
I &= \left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right)  \int \dfrac{ du } {\left( \dfrac{4 }{ 3} \right) u^2 + 1 }
\end{align*}
Now let $v = \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{3} }{2 }\right) u$. We have:
\begin{align*}
dv &= \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{3} }{2 } \right) du \\
du &= \left( \dfrac{ 2 }{ \sqrt{3} } \right) dv \\
I &= \left( \dfrac{3(2)}{2\sqrt{3} }\right) \int
 \dfrac{ dv }
  { \left( \dfrac{4}{3} \right) \left( \dfrac{3}{4}\right) v^2 + 1 } \\
%
I &= \left( \dfrac{3(2)}{2\sqrt{3} }\right) \int
 \dfrac{ dv }{  v^2 + 1 } \\
I &= \sqrt{3} \int
 \dfrac{ dv }{  v^2 + 1 } \\
I &= \sqrt{3} \arctan\left( v \right) + C
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ I = \sqrt{3}
 \arctan\left( \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{3} }{2} \right) \left( x + \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \right) + C $$

However, an online integral calculator gets:
$$  I = 
 \dfrac{ 2 \arctan\left( \dfrac{ 2x+1 }{ \sqrt{3} } \right)  }
 { \sqrt{3} } + C $$
Where did I go wrong?

Here is an updated answer. I believe it is right. I am hoping somebody can confirm that.

$$ \int \dfrac{ dx } {x^2 + x + 1} $$
Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ dx }
    {\left( x + \dfrac{1}{2}\right) ^2 + \dfrac{3}{4} }
\end{align*}
Now we use the substitution $u = x + \dfrac{1}{2}$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ du } {u^2 + \dfrac{3}{4} } \\
I &=
 \left( \dfrac{4}{3} \right)  \int \dfrac{ du } {\left( \dfrac{4 }{ 3} \right) u^2 + 1 }
\end{align*}
Now let $v = \left( \dfrac{ 2  }{ \sqrt{3} }\right) u$. We have:
\begin{align*}
dv &= \left( \dfrac{ 2  }{ \sqrt{3} } \right) du \\
du &= \left( \dfrac{  \sqrt{3}  }{ 2 } \right) dv \\
I &= \left( \dfrac{4}{3}\right) \left( \dfrac{ \sqrt{3} }{2}\right)
 \int \dfrac{ dv }{  v^2 + 1 } \\
%
I &= \left( \dfrac{ 2\sqrt{3} }{3}\right) \arctan( v ) \\
%
\end{align*}
Hence the answer is:
$$ I = \left( \dfrac{ 2\sqrt{3} }{3}\right)
 \arctan\left( \left( \dfrac{2}{ \sqrt{3} }\right)
 \left( x + \dfrac{1}{2} \right) \right)  \\ $$

An online integral calculator gets:
$$  I = 
 \dfrac{ 2 \arctan\left( \dfrac{ 2x+1 }{ \sqrt{3} } \right)  }
 { \sqrt{3} } + C $$
The answers are equivalent.

Comment: when you pulled out the fraction $\frac{3}{4}$ from the denominator from the integral, since it was in the denominator, you should have taken out the reciprocal. So $\frac{4}{3} \int \frac{du}{\frac{4}{3}u^2+1}$

Comment: Also, you should have $v=(2/\sqrt
3 )u$

Answer (score 0):

You need to justify your substitution $u$, you can do that because:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(x+1/2)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} = \int \frac{1}{(x+1/2)^2 + \frac{3}{4}} \cdot 1 \; dx \quad \text{  and  } \quad 1 = (x+ 1/2)'$$

After this,

$$I  = \int \frac{du}{u^2 + \frac{3}{4}} = \int \frac{du}{\frac{3}{4}(\frac{4}{3}u^2+1)} = \frac{1}{\frac{3}{4}}\int \frac{du}{\frac{4}{3}u^2+1} = \frac{4}{3}\int \frac{du}{\frac{4}{3}u^2+1}$$

So,

$$\frac{4}{3}\int \frac{du}{\frac{4}{3}u^2+1} = \frac{4}{3}\int \frac{du}{\left(\frac{2u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1} = \frac{4}{3} \arctan{\frac{2u}{\sqrt{3}}} + c, c \in \mathbb{R}$$

Make the substitution initial $u= x+ \frac{1}{2}$,

$$ = \frac{4}{3} \arctan{\frac{2 (x + \frac{1}{2})}{\sqrt{3}}} + c = \frac{4}{3} \arctan{\frac{2 \sqrt{3} x + 1}{3}} + c, c \in \mathbb{R}$$